# vue updating data on create()

Tags: vue.js, axios, state

I am trying to update an array from my view data() inside my created hook() but my console says that the allFish is undefined. I'm not so great with vue data scoping yet and I was hoping someone could let me know if this is a diction issue, or if there's a better way to update my data on create() when receiving data from a get request and then adding it to an array inside my data.

my current app.vue

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    WebMap
  },
  data: () => ({
    coords: {
      latitude: -118,
      longitude: 34,
    },

    date: '',
    fishType: '',
    allFish: []

  }),

  created(){
    this.allFish = this.fetchFishLocations()
  },

  methods: {

    fetchFishLocations(){

         axios.get('http://localhost:3000/allFish')
            .then(function (response) {
              // handle success
              console.log(response.data.fish);
              return response.data.fish
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              // handle error
              console.log(error);
            })

    },


    async updateCenter() {
      console.log(this.allFish)   //check to see if allFish is defined
      await this.getLocation();
      this.addFishToDb()
    },

  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function which is called fetchFishLocations just returns undefined.
You'd better learn about the use of promise.
By the way, it's easier to use the arrow function

```
// solution 1
created(){
    this.fetchFishLocations()
},
methods: {
    fetchFishLocations(){
         const that = this
         axios.get('http://localhost:3000/allFish')
            .then(function (response) {
              // handle success
              console.log(response.data.fish);
              that.allFish = response.data.fish
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              // handle error
              console.log(error);
            })
    }
}

// solution 2
created(){
    const that = this
    this.fetchFishLocations()
        .then(function (response) {
              // handle success
              console.log(response.data.fish);
              that.allFish = response.data.fish
            })
        .catch(function (error) {
              // handle error
              console.log(error);
            })
},
methods: {
    fetchFishLocations(){
         return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/allFish')
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, your first solution worked for me :) I had tried something similar but forgot to define 'this' in the beginning of my function, I should probably spend more time reviewing vue scoping and hooks too xD

Comment: Happy to help 

Answer (score -1):

You need fill allFish in axios->then method.

```
...
created() {
  this.fetchFishLocations();
},
methods: {
    fetchFishLocations(){

         axios.get('http://localhost:3000/allFish')
            .then(function (response) {
              // handle success
              console.log(response.data.fish);
              this.allFish = response.data.fish;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              // handle error
              console.log(error);
            })

    },
}
...
```